# Как запретить масштабирование текста в приложении Flutter?

Tags: flutter, шрифты, текст, масштабирование

В телефонах есть возможность изменения размера и масштабирования текста на экране:
[image: пример масштаба экрана]
[image: пример размера шрифта]

При изменении размера, в моем приложении написанном на Flutter некоторые элементы съезжают. Каким образом в приложении написанном на Flutter можно запретить изменения размера текста и его масштаба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа:

1)Указывать вручную `textScaleFactor`:

```
Text('text', textScaleFactor: 1.0),
```

2)Переопределить `textScaleFactor` для всего приложения в MediaQuery:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WidgetsApp(
    builder: (context, child) {
      final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
      return MediaQuery(
        data: mediaQueryData.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: child,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проверил только что, это работает если в телефоне был изменен размер шрифта. Однако если менять масштаб текста в телефоне, то текст все равно масштабируется. Есть ли какой то способ, запретить масшабирование элементов на экране?

Comment: @Leksor а вы указываете `fontSize`, для текста?

Comment: да, указываю размер текста.

Comment: @Leksor тогда я не понимаю что еще у вас меняется. Можете приложить пару скриншотов?